# Will my existing VoIP phone work if I install Tor?

Tags: tor, voip

I currently don't use Tor and I have VoIP - a physical phone using a provider's VoIP service over my Internet connection. If I install Tor, will I still be able to make and receive phone calls with my VoIP phone? I am not concerned about the privacy of the phone calls, I just want to be able to use the phone.

Comment: Your phone doesn't care nor know what happens on your computer, if you're using Tor on your computer that doesn't affect other devices on your network.

Comment: Now, if you actually want to make your phone use Tor you'd need to have two network interfaces on your computer and make it forward all traffic received on one of them through Tor, and then connect your phone to that interface. But the main question is : your phone provider knows your identity anyway, so what's the purpose of using Tor for it ?

Comment: Wrong @André Daniel the best and fast way to configure tor over all network devices is at the router level , just configure your router to redirect everything to tor network just like you do with vpn

Comment: @Freedom yeah that's what I said, we use the computer as a router. Do you know many consumer grade routers with built-in Tor support ? I don't, and Tor is very different from conventional VPNs so even if your router has a VPN client you can't use it with Tor.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases,  your ISP has separated your voice traffic from your data services. Your modem is still the endpoint for traffic, but likely using different addresses for data/voice.

Heavy utilization can cause breakup to separated voice services but shouldn't be negatively impacted by tor.

Comment: Separate VLANs for voice and internet traffic are sometimes used when the modem has an FXS port, but when the phone is separate it often connects to the SIP server through the Internet and the modem doesn't know nor care about that.

Comment: Sounds like an accurate answer would depend on the phones connection to the voip provider.  Whether the line is a fxs port on modem or ip phone routed through his local network to the internet.

Comment: Well he clearly said that he had a physical VoIP phone (connected either via Wi-Fi or Ethernet), so the modem is irrelevant here and sees the phone as any other computer accessing the internet.

Comment: Ah,  thank you for clarifying.  I had not picked up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still use it. When you install the Tor browser bundle, it uses a local proxy which forwards the traffic through Tor network. Unless you explicitly configure your VoIP to use that proxy, it'll work just as before.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why it will not work, but it will probably be really slow (since your connection goes through much more computers inside the Tor network). Also you have to accept that someone might literally listen to your connection.

Comment: SIP supports encryption, if that's enabled on both the server and the phone then nobody can listen in.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use Tor on any device you want and that should not interfere with others devices on network.

While you can router all devices to Tor using your router is not recommended since it is not a guarantee of 100% anonymity and will slow down all your devices.

If your VoIP does not use encryption then you will only expose yourself even more and draw more attention since many Tor exit nodes are actually controlled by the government , if your VoIP uses encryption then your communications are already safe and you don't need to use Tor.

Resuming Tor will not make your VoIP safer and can possibly only draw more attention on you,  you should look for VoIP services that use know safe encryption methods for safe communication.

Comment: _many Tor exit nodes are actually controlled by the government_ [citation needed]